# Подскажите пожалуйста. gulp-webp не работает

Tags: gulp

Пакет gulp-webp не работает, пробовал откатится на старые версии, переписать как-то функцию, убрал gulp-imagemin, пробовал разные пути к файлам, много часов муаюсь не могу нагуглить как решить проблему с ошибкой, помогите пожалуйста.

[image: Функция]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Для тех у кого такая же проблема, помогло откатить версию пакета на 3.0.0